# Spring Batch: Jobs does not process as per throttle limit

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-batch

I have a multithreaded step configured with chunk commit-interval of 10 and throttle limit of 5. When I run a batch, ItemReader reads first fifty jobs(I think it's based on commit-interval and throttle limit) and process 5 jobs at a time(based on throttle-limit) then write's it. Till now it works fine.

After this, it does not read the next fifty jobs at a time and only one or two job(s) processing at a time until the end of remaining jobs.

Based on the throttle limit 5 should have been running at a time. I see no socket or any other exceptions.

I am new to spring batch, correct me if I am wrong at anything.

Here is how I have configured:

```
@Bean
public Job executeConcurrentJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("executeConcurrentJob")
            .listener(listener())
            .start(step1())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
}

@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").allowStartIfComplete(true)
            .<BatchJob,BatchJob>chunk(10)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .throttleLimit(5)
            .build();
}
```

Thanks in Advance!